# Add a common legend for several barcharts Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 5x3 barcharts all of them have the same legend. I'm wondering if there is a way so that I can combine them all in one figure and have only one big legend as a row in the end instead of putting 15 tiny little legends in each figure? If anyone could please advise.

Comment: as I said in the other question, you can use `subplot`

Comment: let me answer this one first

Comment: Kindly review my answer and accept it if it works for you

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm wondering now how to add a common legend in the bottom (row) instead of adding legends in each subplot, because in my case the legend is the same in all 15 plots

Comment: Yup, it should be as simple as this!
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98474-is-there-a-command-in-matlab-for-creating-one-overall-legend-when-i-have-a-figure-with-subplots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is below and you can simply use `subplot` to plot multiple plots into 1 image.

```
A = rand(4);
subplot(5,3,1)
bar( A );
subplot(5,3,2)
bar( A );
subplot(5,3,3)
bar( A );
subplot(5,3,4)
bar( A );
subplot(5,3,5)
bar( A );
subplot(5,3,6)
bar( A );
...
```

If you want 5x3 plots, then the first 2 parameters are 5 and 3 respectively. The third parameter is just an index of this plot. Call `subplot` before plotting and you're good to go!

Here is the result
[image]

If you wish to create a legend common for all plots, then you can use the [suggestion here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158948). Just create the legend for the last one and position it at `SouthOutside`. You will need to increase the number of rows by 1 and cover double the area to have enough room for the legend.

```
ax1 = subplot(4,1,1);
plot(rand(30,2))
ax2 = subplot(4,1,2);
plot(rand(30,2))
ax3 = subplot(4,1,3:4);
plot(rand(30,2))
legend({'first','second'},'Location','SouthOutside')
```

This is the result.

[image]

Comment: but why I would need to grab the bar-plots of every subplot? I mean they are the same so why I would need to do that?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, from what you just said I'm guessing you wanted a "common" legend for all the plots?

Comment: If that's the case, this method would work.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158948

Comment: Just put it below all the subplots or wherever you want!

Comment: The key line is `legend({'first','second'},'Location','EastOutside')`. You can simply do it on the outside and set it to `'SouthOutside'`

Comment: Let me know if that addresses your concern. Also, let me know if the scatter plot works for the other one. If not, we can work from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76120/discussion-between-shepherd-and-krisdestruction).